# 2D array is printing the wrong way

Tags: c

I'm creating a 2D dynamic array to keep track of transactions over several days. I have created the 2D array and added the transactions. The problem is that is not printing the correct transactions. It will print correctly if I have the same amount of noOfdays and transcount. Ex 3 and 2. But it changes values if I have noOfdays 2 and trascount 3.

Example output having noOfdays 2 and trascount 3.

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

int noOfDays, transcount;
printf("Enter no of days:");
scanf("%d", &noOfDays);
printf("Enter total no of transaction:\n ");
scanf("%d", &transcount);
int *p= (int)malloc(noOfDays*transcount * sizeof(int));

int number = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < noOfDays; i++) {
  printf("Enter no of transaction per day:\n", i);
for (int j = 0; j < transcount; j++) {
  scanf("%d", &number);
  p[i*noOfDays + j] = number;
 }

}

printf("%s\n", "#Printing your 2d array:" );
for (int i = 0; i < noOfDays; i++){
 for (int j = 0; j < transcount; j++){
  int number = p[i*noOfDays + j];
  printf("%d\t", number);
}
printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show a [mcve], including complete source code (including `#include <stdio.h>`) that others can compile without changes, sample input, the output you get from that input, and the output you want from that input.

Comment: Remove `(int)` from `int *p= (int)malloc(noOfDays*transcount * sizeof(int));`. `malloc` returns a `void *` that will be implicitly converted to `int *`, and converting it to `int` is not what you want.

Comment: The `, i` in `printf("Enter no of transaction per day:\n", i);` is not used and is unnecessary. Remove it. Your compiler should have warned you about that. If it did not, turn on warnings in your compiler and pay attention to them.

Comment: With those fixed and `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>` added, the code behaves as I would expect given input of “3 2 4 5 6 7 8 9”; it prints 3 rows of two columns containing 4 and 5, 6 and 7, and 8 and 9. This is why you must provide an [mcve] including input and output: We need to know what you think is wrong with the output.

Comment: change this `p[i*noOfDays+j]` to this `p[i*transcount+j]`. your index formula is not correct.

Comment: I made some changes to my question and added an image of the output I'm getting @EricPostpischil

Comment: @ChiefC: And now you have an answer. However, in the future, paste input and output as text, not as an image. You can mark it as preformatted text (the `<pre>…</pre>` tag in the markup) so that Stack Overflow formats it in a suitable style.

Comment: will do @EricPostpischil thanks for the help and suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably your index formula in `p[i*noOfDays+j]` is not correct.

Change it from `p[i*noOfDays+j]` to `p[i*transcount+j]`.

The reason is the `i` is the index of the current transaction group.
The `j` is the index of specific transaction in a day.